# How to mask specific rows elements of matrix in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have a matrix `A` with `A[:,1]` as `Bus_id`. So `Bus_id` are 1,3,4, and 6. For processing, I equated `Bus_id`'s to consecutive row indexing, see `A_new` matrix.

```
julia> A=[1 1 3;3 1 1; 4 1 7;6 1 1]
4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1  3
 3  1  1
 4  1  7
 6  1  1


julia> A_new
 1  1  1
 2  1  1
 3  1  1
 4  1  1
```

Now, I have another matrix `B`, which has some elements of matrix `A`. I wish to convert `B` matrix's bus_ids to `b_new`. I don't know how to explain this problem.

```
julia> B= [3 1 1; 4 1 7]
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  1  1
 6  1  1

julia> B_new
 2  1  1
 4  1  7
```

I have tried masking by it works only for one element.

Please help me find a way.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is almost impossible to understand. One of the main reasons is probably that you have not formatted your example code properly. You can get some tips here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks   It is also important that what you post is consistent and makes sense. What is `b_new` for example?  I suggest that you take the time to re-write your question completely, and make it much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are using Bus_id as an index. If you want to renumber the business ID's, but not lose track of transactions indexed with the original business id's, what you want to do fits naturally into a `Dict` that translates the Bus_id from one to another.

One problem that immediately arises is what should happen if some of the entries in B have no translation from A, but are already set to a number that is in A's new key? Potential cross-linked database chaos! Instead, the new ids need to be unique if at all possible! I suggest making them negative.

If you use matrix A as your key to translation (and assuming that all entries in  `A[:,1]`  are unique--if not the logic might need to drop duplicates first) the dict usage then looks like this:

```
A = [1 1 3; 3 1 1; 4 1 7; 6 1 1]
B = [3 1 1; 6 1 1]

function consecutive_row_indexing(mat)
    dict = Dict{Int, Int}()
    for (i,n) in enumerate(mat[:,1])
        dict[n] = -i
    end
    dict
end

function renumberbus_ids!(mat, dict)
    for i in 1:size(mat)[1]
        if haskey(dict, mat[i,1])
           mat[i,1] = dict[mat[i,1]]
        end
    end
    mat
end

d = consecutive_row_indexing(A)
println(renumberbus_ids!(A, d))
println(renumberbus_ids!(B, d))


output: <code> 
[-1 1 3; -2 1 1; -3 1 7; -4 1 1]
[-2 1 1; -4 1 1]
```

If you still really want your B matrix with positive integers for its index column, just replace = -i with = i on the seventh line of the code above.